# facebook be like Notification logic

Tags: php

I have my table from post , post_id, admin_id,content,date_created,status while table comment , post_id, admin_id, content, date_posted, status. so how can notification specifically.

----this is my sample  sql query that i made.-----

```
$result= mysql_query("SELECT admin_id from comment inner join post on post.post_id = comment.post_id where comment.status = 1 AND post.post_id = comment.post_id");

    $row= mysql_fetch_array ($result); 
    $id=$row['admin_id'];

$commentcount =   mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) from comment inner join post on post.post_id = comment.post_id where comment.status = 1 AND post.admin_id = $id"),0);

if ($id == $id_session) {
        echo $commentcount;

} 
else {
    //echo $postcount;
}
```

i am looking forward to hear from you guys. i am a student/new member on this so please keep your answer as simple as possible. thank you.

Comment: First of all. stop using mysql_* functions. They're deprecated. Use `mysqli_*` or `PDO_` instead. Second, take a look at http://bobby-tables.com for information about SQL injection. Your code is not safe at all!!! Last point: Can you please describe your problem a bit better? For me its totally unclear what you're asking.

Comment: sorry cause im a newbie, my problem is i didn't know what is the logic for a notification system

Comment: Stackoverflow is here to help you with specific programming problems, not to give you the "know-how" ... so this question is quite off topic here.Regardless, a notificationsystem (especially if real-time requirement) is much more complex than simple 2 SQL querys.